# Why is Firefox not honoring flexed div's height, but Chrome is?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, flexbox

This is best illustrated with a simple example.

I have a container with `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column`, with a single div inside with `height: 300px` and `flex: 1`.

Chrome renders the nested div at 300px tall, but Firefox renders it as a single line. Is this just a nuance between the implementation of flexbox between the two browsers, or is this bad code somehow? If a nuance, what's the best way to mitigate?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container > div {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
  flex: 1;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Single line in Firefox, but 300px tall in Chrome!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `flex: 1` shorthand rule breaks down as follows:

- `flex-grow: 1`
- `flex-shrink: 1`
- `flex-basis: 0`

Chrome sees this, but overrides `flex-basis` with `height: 300px`.

Firefox sees this, but *does not* override `flex-basis` with `height: 300px`.

The simple cross-browser solution is to get rid of the `height` rule and just use:

```
flex: 1 0 300px
```

In terms of the spec, Firefox has the correct behavior:

> [**7.1. The `flex`
>   Shorthand**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-property)
>
> When a box is a flex item, `flex` is consulted instead of the main
>   size property to determine the main size of the box.
>
> The flex item’s [main size
>   property](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#main-size-property) is
>   either the `width` or `height` property.

Comment: If someone cares, Edge exhibits the correct behaviour as well :)