# Flex in Firefox shrinks images automatically, but not in Chrome

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```html
<h1>Window width:</h1>

<div style="display: flex">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/225?image=10" alt="1">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/225?image=11" alt="2">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/225?image=12" alt="3">
</div>

<h1>Wrapped in 500px wide div:</h1>

<div style="width: 500px; overflow: auto">
  <div style="display: flex">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/225?image=10" alt="1">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/225?image=11" alt="2">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/225?image=12" alt="3">
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what the result looks like in Firefox:

[image: Screenshot of page in Firefox 53]

This is what the result looks like in Chrome:

[image: Screenshot of page in Chrome 59]

As you can see, in Firefox, the images have been nicely shrunk and resized, so that all there images fit in one line without wrapping or cropping. On Chrome, the images remain in their original sizes, which causes cropping in small windows or divs.

Is this expected? Am I doing something wrong? How can I get the same result in both Firefox and Chrome?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These are initial settings in a flex container:

- `flex-grow: 0`
- `flex-shrink: 1`
- `flex-basis: auto`

The shorthand would be:

- `flex: 0 1 auto`

Therefore, even though you haven't specified these rules in your code, they apply to the images.

The images cannot grow, they can shrink (equally and just enough to avoid overflowing the container), and they are initially sized to their natural width (400px).

This is what you're seeing in Firefox. The images are shrinking to fit nicely within the container.

*In Firefox, flex rules are overriding the natural dimensions of the image.*

*In Chrome, however, the reverse is true. The dimensions of the images are prevailing.*

The simple cross-browser solution is to wrap the images in another element, so this new wrapper becomes the flex item and takes on the default `flex: 0 1 auto`, and nothing needs to be overridden.

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Window width:</h1>

<div style="display: flex">
  <span><img src="https://unsplash.it/400/225?image=10" alt="1"></span>
  <span><img src="https://unsplash.it/400/225?image=11" alt="2"></span>
  <span><img src="https://unsplash.it/400/225?image=12" alt="3"></span>
</div>

<h1>Wrapped in 500px wide div:</h1>

<div style="width: 500px; overflow: auto">
  <div style="display: flex">
    <span><img src="https://unsplash.it/400/225?image=10" alt="1"></span>
    <span><img src="https://unsplash.it/400/225?image=11" alt="2"></span>
    <span><img src="https://unsplash.it/400/225?image=12" alt="3"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

In terms of which browser is adhering to spec guidance, it *appears* that would be Firefox. In a flex container, flex rules should prevail:

> [**7.1. The `flex`
>   Shorthand**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-property)
>
> When a box is a flex item, `flex` is consulted instead of the main size property to determine the main size of the box.
>
> The flex item’s [main size property](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#main-size-property) is either the `width` or `height` property.

I say Firefox "appears" to be correct because the spec is saying that flex rules should prevail over the CSS `width` and `height` properties.

Of course, the dimensions of the images in this case are not defined in CSS. They are the natural dimensions of the image. So this scenario may be left open for interpretation, and Chrome may not be violating any guidelines.

However, in another scenario, where the `height` property was a factor, Firefox stuck with `flex`, while Chrome went with `height`: [Why is Firefox not honoring flexed div's height, but Chrome is?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44484407/3597276)

Comment: "nothing needs to be overridden." except for the `width` property of the `img` elements, which need to be set to `100%`.

Comment: There is no `width` property defined in the original code. My `img` rule is sizing the image to fit inside its container, and nothing is being overridden (at least in the CSS).

Comment: Also, the image is no longer a flex item. I was referring to the inconsistency among browsers relating to the sizing of flex items. That's no longer an issue.

Comment: I filed a bug with Chrome, so we can see whether this is something they should fix or not: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=982188

Answer (score 4):

I this case, add `align-items: flex-start` to the flex container, and then this rule to the images

```
img {
  min-width: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

As `align-items` defaults to `stretch`, so they stretches, then `min-width` defaults to `auto` which again tell them to be their original size, and finally, give them `width: 100%` so they fit horizontally and adjust its height to maintain aspect ratio.

*Note, after quick browser test, this won't work on IE11 (but works on Edge), so bugs exists little bit everywhere, based on the used code. The second option, where one wraps the image's, works on IE11 though.*

Stack snippet

```css
img {
  min-width: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Window width:</h1>

<div style="display: flex; align-items: flex-start;">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/225?image=10" alt="1">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/225?image=11" alt="2">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/225?image=12" alt="3">
</div>

<h1>Wrapped in 500px wide div:</h1>

<div style="width: 500px; overflow: auto">
  <div style="display: flex; align-items: flex-start;">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/225?image=10" alt="1">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/225?image=11" alt="2">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/225?image=12" alt="3">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Another option is to wrap the images, and set the `img` to `width: 100%`

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex;">
  <div>
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/225?image=10" alt="1">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/225?image=11" alt="2">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/225?image=12" alt="3">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

This post, [css3-flexbox-maintain-image-aspect-ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30788131/css3-flexbox-maintain-image-aspect-ratio), has links together with a good explanation, about how/why the browsers render differently

Comment: Great answer! Although, I'm still puzzled why the default behaviour is different in Firefox from Chrome. `min-width` defaults to `auto` in Firefox too, and `align-items` defaults to `normal` in both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: That is Flexbox bugs that cause them to behave different, and this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/30792956/2827823,  has a good explanation together with links. I will link to that answer in mine

Comment: @Michael_B And Edge has `auto`... and plus 1 for your explanation ... I often has the _how's_, but not so often to explain the _why's_ :)